# Sorting users by country code

Tags: mysql, sql

Ive got a query here, i'd like it to list the countries by the most country count. However, its giving me an error, if anyone can help it would be much appreciated!

**Here is the query!**

```
SELECT country_code,count(country_code) FROM `users` 
GROUP BY country_code
ORDER BY `users`.`id`
DESC LIMIT 50;
```

So it'd be like

| US | 150 |

| CA | 200 |

**Table Structure**

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
      `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `real_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `mail` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'defaultuser@other.org',
      `rank` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `motto` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'I love Fatal Hotel!',
      `account_created` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `last_online` int(15) NOT NULL,
      `online` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `ip_last` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
      `ip_reg` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
      `home_room` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `daily_respect_points` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '3',
      `daily_pet_respect_points` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '3',
      `newbie_status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `is_muted` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `mutant_penalty` enum('0','1','2') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `mutant_penalty_expire` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `block_newfriends` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `hide_online` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `hide_inroom` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `vip` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `logged` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `points` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `country_code` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `profile_status` enum('0','1','2') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=FIXED AUTO_INCREMENT=467835 ;
```

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: thats pretty confusing, why order by `users.id` provide the table structure.

Comment: You need `select country_code,count(*) as tot from users group by country_code order by tot limit 50`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty it lists all accounts i just want last 50 that have registered which is why i used ID as order by

Comment: Then do as `select country_code,count(*) as tot from (select country_code from users order by id desc limit 50)x`

Comment: http://i.gyazo.com/3874c5c397704681700d2aaee2223f7f.png @AbhikChakraborty thats what it shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT country_code,count(country_code) AS 'Total' FROM `users` 
GROUP BY country_code
ORDER BY 'Total' DESC) t LIMIT 50;
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ab5f5/6)

Comment: it shows this http://i.gyazo.com/a9cd257ebe96e88c1a8b1731163ec0f9.png i just want last 50 records in the table the screenshot shows all records in the database.

Comment: Move the `LIMIT 50` to inside the bracket

Comment: @JoshPitcher I'm beginning to think there is something wrong with the tool you are using. It works perfectly in SQLFiddle.

Comment: @PhilWalton thank you for the help, ill try to see whats wrong here. but that query should be working

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
SELECT country_code,count(country_code) as total FROM `users` 
GROUP BY country_code
ORDER BY total
DESC LIMIT 50;
```